# Hiding DataTables columns at specific breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, datatables

## Problem

I have two DataTables — one is five columns and the other is four columns — and **I'm looking for a way to hide columns at specific screen widths.**

## What I've tried

When I resize the browser, both tables automatically appear to drop down to a two-column chart at 480 pixels in width, but I need additional breakpoints in-between where I'm dropping additional columns since they don't fit inside viewport.

- Adding a class of `responsive` to the table as seen in this [example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html)
- I've tried using [column control helper classes](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html) to remove columns at certain breakpoints, but even adding the class `none` did not hide a column
- Adding classes to the `<th>` in the `thead` to take advantage of their [responsive breakpoints](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.breakpoints)
- I've include `responsive: true` in my DataTables options

### scripts.js

```
$('#test-scores').dataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0,1,2]).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var colIdx = column.index();
                // adjust label for dropdown according to index
                // TODO - colIdx is producing 0
                if (colIdx === 0) {
                    var label = 'districts';
                }
                else if (colIdx === 1) {
                    var label = 'schools';
                }
                else {
                    var label = 'subjects';
                }

                var select = $('.select--map-' + label)
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $(this).val();
                        if ( val == '*' ) {
                            column
                                .search( '' )
                                .draw();
                        }
                        else {
                            val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex( val );
                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        }
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                });
            });
        },
        "pageLength": 25, // The number of entries per page
        "order": [0, 'asc'], // First column in ascending order, previous "3, desc"
        "responsive": true,
        "searching": true,
        "columns": [
        { "data": "district",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/schools/' + makeSlug(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }
        },
        { "data": "school",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<a href="/schools/' + makeSlug(row['district']) + '/' + makeSlug(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
            }
        },
        { "data": "subject" },
        { 
            "data": "rate",
            // https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Built-in-helpers
            // Render.number() parameters: thousands separator, decimal separator, decimal places, prefix, suffix
            "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 1, '', '%' ) 
        },
        { 
            "data": "test_takers", 
            // Render.number() parameters: thousands separator, decimal separator, decimal places, prefix, suffix
            "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '', '' ) 
        }
        ],
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{% static 'schools/json/school_map_scores.json' %}"
                }
    });
```

### index.html

```
<table id="test-scores" class="table table-striped responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-district none">District</th>
            <th class="table-school none">School</th>
            <th class="table-subject none">Subject</th>
            <th class="table-proficiency none">Pct. proficient</th>
            <th class="table-testtakers none">No. of test takers</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If your table is overflowing within a flexbox but not elsewhere you may have encountered a display issue because of it
If that's the case, adding `overflow: hidden;flex-shrink:1;` to the closest flex element will solve the issue

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand the logic above, but perhaps you overcomplicate the problem? I would look at [**`column.visible()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()) and respond to the `onresize` event. Here is a dead simple example :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  autoWidth: false //set to false, so dataTables not ruin the idea
})
```

create a `onresize` handler,  trigger immediately so columns is automatically hidden on small devices :

```
window.onresize = function() {
  var w = this.innerWidth;
  table.column(5).visible( w > 700);
  table.column(4).visible( w > 600);
  table.column(3).visible( w > 500);
  table.column(2).visible( w > 400);
  table.column(1).visible( w > 300);  
}
//trigger upon pageload
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4xL6d5xa/**

Try resize the right bottom pane.

---

```
var table;
window.onresize = function() {
  if (!table) return;
  var w = this.innerWidth;
  table.api().column(5).visible( w > 700);
  ...
}
table = $('#test-scores').dataTable({
  ...
  initComplete: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).trigger('resize');
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Handling of resize events is not recommended like that for performance reasons. It should be [debounced](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) instead. Besides Responsive extension already includes [necessary classes](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) where breakpoints could be customized using [`responsive.breakpoints`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.breakpoints) option.

Comment: @davidkonrad Do you mind showing me how / where you would incorporate your snippet into my code so that there are no scoping issues.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, that is very true (great article) *if* we talk general terms. I guess the `onresize` example mostly is for educational reasons. Actually [onresize is not triggered that much](http://jsfiddle.net/4xL6d5xa/8/) compared to many other potential performance lowering events (GUI events like scroll, mouse or things you trigger when certain circumstances come true) in this case you will expect the `onresize` to be triggered once (on mobile) or very seldom (on desktop). Besides that, when manic people resizes their browser they are not doing anything else == only one task to perform.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen, You could declare `table` as a global variable (if you for some reason is using readys', otherwise table will automatically be available within the `onresize` handler)  Then trigger resize in the `initComplete` callback,. You will need a timeout since `table` not is set before the `dataTable()` function is exited. **http://jsfiddle.net/4xL6d5xa/10/** (now using `dataTable`, not `DataTable`)

Comment: This solution completely hides the information instead of adding it to the responsive collapse, so some information will not be accessible on certain screen sizes. Not a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using the Responsive extension of DataTable, you can use the [responsivePriority](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority) option to obtain the desired behavior, it will automatically calculate what columns should be hidden based on the space available for the table and the defined priority

> Note: the priority is reversed, meaning a higher priority column will
>   be hidden before a lower priority

```js
$('#test-scores').dataTable({
  //...
  responsive: true,
  columns: [
    { data: "district", responsivePriority: 1 },
    { data: "school", responsivePriority: 2 },
    { data: "subject", responsivePriority: 3 },
    { data: "rate", responsivePriority: 4 },
    { data: "test_takers", responsivePriority: 5 },
  ],
  //...
});
```

## Example

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  responsive: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="nowrap" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="0">Seq.</th> <!-- The first column should always be visible or the collapsed data will not be visible -->
      <th data-priority="1">Name</th>
      <th data-priority="3">Position</th>
      <th data-priority="4">Office</th>
      <th data-priority="5">Start date</th>
      <th data-priority="1">Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Seq.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>54</td>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```